# jquery replacing not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I've a problem with jQuery replaceWith function. It is not replacing but appending the new entry.

```
function updateList() {
  $.ajax({ url:"query.cgi", data: { update: true } }).done(function(response) {
    var dom = $("#listEvents");
    for(var i in response) {
      var item = $("#" + response[i].id + "-row");
      var html = $($.templates("#templateEvent").render(response));
      if(item.length > 0) {
        item.replaceWith(html);
        //html.replaceAll(item);
      } else {
        dom.append(html);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The new html content is rendered by jsRender and the generated object has the same id as the old one. But this shouldn't be a problem in my opinion.

Do I've to remove the old entry first and then insert the new? But how can I get the correct position for the insertion?

Comment: Isn't the issue that you render the same `response` in each iteration of the loop? Doesn't that create duplication? Shouldn't you be only rendering part of `response` based on `i`? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is `response` an object of elements? arrays?

Comment: Ohh, thats like a slap in the face. Off course it is...
I spent hours for trying and looking for the reason and it's so easy.